# Hiding mouse cursor on Mac OS X when using Synergy

Tags: macos, synergy, mouse-cursor

When using Synergy on my Mac, if my mouse leaves the screen, the cursor jumps to the middle. Sometimes this is a problem because the cursor can obscure the middle of the screen, trigger a hover effect, is ugly, etc.

I was wondering if there's a work around for this. Optimally the cursor would be hidden or would stay at the location where it "left" the screen. Moving the cursor to a defined spot might work as well. Is there a setting, or an app for this issue?

(Note: The cursor disappears on my Windows machines and Linux)

Comment: I sometimes find the mouse cursor on my Mac synergy client does not reappear when moving back onto its screen. Switching windows with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> makes it visible again, so doing this twice is an acceptable if slightly time-consuming workaround for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known problem with Mac Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/143).  As of Sep 2011, a possible fix has been found, but not yet incorporated into the stable branch.  Right now the stable Mac release is 1.3.7, and this fix is slated to be included in version 1.3.9 due out in [early November](http://synergy-foss.org/roadmap/#1.3.9).

Switching to using their beta version (currently 1.4.3) should fix it, but might introduce other problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Synergy works - when the mouse goes off the screen, it is moved back to the centre and hidden.  Sometimes if a program interferes with the mouse cursor (or you use the mouse attached to the machine) it will reappear.

Have a look at the apps you have running to see if any are causing this behaviour.

Comment: There's a problem with the Mac version of Synergy that causes the mouse not to be hidden--it just goes to the center of the screen and obscures/interacts with whatever program happens to be there.